# How to add results of two mysql columns and echo results in php/html doc

Tags: php, mysql, addition, calculated-columns

I am in the process of building an expense tracker for my wife and I using PHP/MySQL. I have already successfully built the database, tables, appropriate PHP files etc. What I'm now hoping to do is add all of the numerical values entered in the expense column together and add all of the numerical values entered in the deposit column as well and have them display at the bottom of the table under the appropriate columns within the PHP "echo" file I have built.

Here is what I have built:

```
<html>
<head>  
   <title>Budget</title>  
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
        <style type="text/css">
             INPUT[type="text"] { font-size: 14pt }
             INPUT[type="password"] { font-size: 14pt }
        </style>  
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/template/engage.png"/>
   </head>  
   <body BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF onorientationchange="updateOrientation();" >
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <h1><img src="Budjet1.gif"></h1>
    <div id="content_left">

<hr>
<?php
$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="database_name";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Day</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Month</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Year</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Transaction</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Category</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Deposit</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Expense</b></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Notes</b></font></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"Day");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"Month");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"Year");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"Transaction");
$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"Category");
$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"Deposit");
$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"Expense");
$f8=mysql_result($result,$i,"Notes");
?>

<tr>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f8; ?></font></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
                 <p><font face="arial" color="#000000" size="4"><a href="enter.php">Make another entry!</a></font></p>
                 <p><font face="arial" color="#000000" size="4"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></font></p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do is have the script add all of the values in the "Expense" column together and display that result below the expense column. Same thing with the "Deposit" column.

I'm kind of new to this stuff so any help you could give would be greatly appreciated. I tested using the following:

```
$sql = "select sum(column) from table";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
```

and then...

```
echo 'Sum: ' . $row[0];
```

but I couldn't get it to show at the bottom of the table. Instead it showed in-between every other row. Also, I'm not sure how to go about getting the results for two separate rows.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying for all of the data anyways, you can just compute the totals within the PHP code. Something like this:

```
$expenseTotal = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $expense = $row['Expense'];
    $expenseTotal += $expense;

    echo "<tr><td>$expense</td></tr>"; //TODO: add other columns
}

echo "<tr><td>$expenseTotal</td></tr>";
```